# how to pass performance counters to SCOM Retrieve Performance Data Rest API?

Tags: performancecounter, scom

I'm trying **SCOM Retrieve Performance Data Rest API** but I'm unable to pass performance counters as it's unclear in their official documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/operationsmanager/data/retrieve%20performance%20data

Example :-

```
## Get performances for the given server



 $myObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
objectname = 'Memory'
countername = 'Available MBytes'
} 
  $uriPerf = "http://$MS/OperationsManager/data/performance"
    $perfFilter = @"
    {
        "duration": 100,
        "id": "103c21b9-1dd1-e6ff-ede8-1091e0111abc",
        "peformanceCounters":[$myObject]
        
    }"@


    $PerfResponse = Invoke-WebRequest `
        -Method POST `
        -Uri $uriPerf `
        -Body $perfFilter `
        -Headers $scomHeaders `
        -Credential $cred `
        -WebSession $websession `
        #-AllowUnencryptedAuthentication

    $perf = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $PerfResponse.Content

    Write-Host "Timestamp after get all get performance data for $($server.id) call $(Get-Date)"
    Write-Host "----------------"
```

**This is the error I'm getting**

```
 Invoke-WebRequest : {"errorMessage":"Passed parameter cannot be null","errorTrace":""}
```